# I THINK my SerialPort is responsible for this ObjectDisposedException but I have no idea where it's happening

Tags: c#, .net, exception, serial-port

I do some very simple error logging in my desktop application which speaks to equipment over a `SerialPort`.  One thing I do is setup a global exception catcher which does nothing but log the stack trace using:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionHandler;
```

I have one user who is having an error that is showing up in his logs. No one else is having the issue. I have no idea where to search for this uncaught exception. And I have no idea where I should try to catch it because I don't fully understand what it is.

I use the .NET `SerialPort` object and all I do in open the port and do some simple reads and writes.

Is anyone able to explain what this exception is/means, what I can do to fix it, or where I should look to try and catch the error? Every time I touch my `SerialPort` object I am doing so within try and catch blocks. So I am at a complete loss.

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success)
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, Boolean& success)
   at Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetOverlappedResult(SafeFileHandle hFile, NativeOverlapped* lpOverlapped, Int32& lpNumberOfBytesTransferred, Boolean bWait)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.EventLoopRunner.WaitForCommEvent()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: "The exception that is thrown when an operation is performed on a disposed object."

Comment: Haha sorry I completely forgot to add the StackTrace

Comment: @O.O My apologies since I didn't have the StackTrace in there when you commented. I realize how that type of exception is thrown. But the trace offers me no information (that I can see) on how to capture it or prevent it. It appears to be a .NET problem.

Comment: @MichaelMankus - it appears the exception is being thrown on a different thread. Move your try-catch block into the thread that does the read/writing and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: @O.O Wow you know that never even occurred to me. The only thing I have threaded to my call to `SerialPort.Close()`. And you are right that I thread my call to that method and therefore my try/catch is not observed. Very silly of me.

Comment: It is caused by the serial port driver that the user is using, it is making the port disappear while you have it in use.  Typically a cr*ppy one that he spent five bucks on.  Next best thing to tell him is to not jerk the USB connector while your program is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the exception is being thrown on a different thread. Move your try-catch block into the thread that does the read/writing and see if that fixes your problem.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983779/catch-exception-that-is-thrown-in-different-thread) question for using Task.

Answer (score 3):

I used some assistance from user [O.O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322518/o-o) and from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113909/objectdisposedexecption-after-closing-a-net-serialport) question. I was doing something silly.

```
public bool OpenPort()
{
    try
    {
        if (_port != null && _port.IsOpen)
        {
            new Thread(_port.Close).Start();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        // Open the port code

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Error handling code
        return false;
    }
}
```

I was doing what you see above. Because I was threading the call to close, my Try/Catch did nothing. And from the answer to the other SO question, it looks like calling `SerialPort.Close()` without also calling `Dispose()` is the issue.

```
public bool OpenPort()
{
    try
    {
        if (_port != null && _port.IsOpen)
        {
            new Thread(CloseSerialPortCleanly).Start();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        // Open the port code

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Error handling code
        return false;
    }
}

private void CloseSerialPortCleanly()
{
    try
    {
        if (_port != null && _port.IsOpen)
        {
            _port.Close();
            _port.Dispose();
            _port = null;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
         // Error handling code
    }
}
```

This has solved the user's issue.