# .net application crashes without an error

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, serial-port

I wrote an application in VB.Net, and somehow it crashes without a reason, for example I run it, it started successfully then after staying non-active for like 10 or more minutes it crashes, without any exception and Visual Studio tells me that process switched to stop mode and application was closed.

My main code isn't looping except that a timer is always enabled with 100ms period, i don't think this is a problem. The funny thing is that the time when process will crash varies.

I tried my application on two Win10 machines. On one of them it doesn't crash at all, and on the other one sometimes crashes. And I tried on Win7, crashes happen regularly after 20min - Windows says "application is not responding, we are closing the app". So why it doesn't show any exceptions in debug mode of VS17, also i turned on all exceptions in debug menu.
first is net runtime  log and second is application log:

```
Имя журнала:   Application
Источник:      .NET Runtime
Дата:          28.04.2018 18:40:02
Код события:   1026
Категория задачи:Отсутствует
Уровень:       Ошибка
Ключевые слова:Классический
Пользователь:  Н/Д
Компьютер:     HV-service-ПК
Описание:
Application: SD CARD Car Master [beta].exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ObjectDisposedException
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean ByRef)
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, Boolean ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetOverlappedResult(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*, Int32 ByRef, Boolean)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream+EventLoopRunner.WaitForCommEvent()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Xml события:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-04-28T07:40:02.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>533</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>HV-service-ПК</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application: SD CARD Car Master [beta].exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ObjectDisposedException
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean ByRef)
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, Boolean ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetOverlappedResult(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*, Int32 ByRef, Boolean)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream+EventLoopRunner.WaitForCommEvent()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Имя журнала:   Application
Источник:      Application Error
Дата:          28.04.2018 18:31:18
Код события:   1000
Категория задачи:(100)
Уровень:       Ошибка
Ключевые слова:Классический
Пользователь:  Н/Д
Компьютер:     HV-service-ПК
Описание:
Имя сбойного приложения: SD CARD Car Master [beta].exe, версия: 1.0.0.0, отметка времени: 0x5ae2a828
Имя сбойного модуля: KERNELBASE.dll, версия: 6.1.7601.17514, отметка времени 0x4ce7b8f0
Код исключения: 0xe0434352
Смещение ошибки: 0x0000b760
Идентификатор сбойного процесса: 0xc9c
Время запуска сбойного приложения: 0x01d3dec2dcbdc3d0
Путь сбойного приложения: C:\Users\HV-service\Desktop\SD CARD Car Master [beta].exe
Путь сбойного модуля: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Код отчета: 238f20b0-4ab6-11e8-b866-001b3822ff72
Xml события:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-04-28T07:31:18.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>531</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>HV-service-ПК</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>SD CARD Car Master [beta].exe</Data>
    <Data>1.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>5ae2a828</Data>
    <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>6.1.7601.17514</Data>
    <Data>4ce7b8f0</Data>
    <Data>e0434352</Data>
    <Data>0000b760</Data>
    <Data>c9c</Data>
    <Data>01d3dec2dcbdc3d0</Data>
    <Data>C:\Users\HV-service\Desktop\SD CARD Car Master [beta].exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>238f20b0-4ab6-11e8-b866-001b3822ff72</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

**Update:** I noticed that the problem in the serial port autoconnect code:

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Connected = False
   autoconnect()
    End Sub
 Private Sub autoconnect()

        For Each sp As String In My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames
            Try
                spObj = New SerialPort(sp, 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)
                spObj.ReadTimeout = 5000
                '    spObj.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 6
                spObj.WriteTimeout = 5000
                spObj.Open()

                Dim ListeningWatch As New Stopwatch
                Dim serialMessage As String

                Dim BytesToSend(1) As Byte
                Dim OutBuffer
                BytesToSend(0) = Hex(99)             ' call Dump eeprom (44)
                BytesToSend(1) = 0                   'dummy
                OutBuffer = BytesToSend

                ' Bytes are outputted in the order of their Index Number(Index)!

                spObj.Write(OutBuffer, 0, OutBuffer.length)

                ListeningWatch.Start()
                While ListeningWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 5000 And ListeningWatch.IsRunning
                    serialMessage = spObj.ReadExisting()
                    'RichTextBox1.Text = serialMessage
                    If serialMessage.Contains("000001020") And serialMessage.Length = 12 Then
                        ListeningWatch.Stop()

                        Connected = True
                        Timer1.Enabled = False
                        DeviceStatus.Text = "SN: " & serialMessage                       
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End While
            Catch ex As Exception
                spObj.Dispose()
            End Try
        Next
        If Connected = False Then
            DeviceStatus.Text = "SN: Not connected"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked event log > Application? It usually logs all such mysterious process crashes.

Comment: Check the console output, here you will able to find the exception. This usually happen when you put a `TryCatch` block on a specific code and then `rethrow` the exception but not manage it.

Comment: If the "doesn't respond" window opens then the error is definitely logged in the Event Log. Look for an entry that says _"Application Error"_. If you've never used the Event Viewer before see this: [**What is the Windows Event Viewer, and How Can I Use It?**](https://www.howtogeek.com/123646/htg-explains-what-the-windows-event-viewer-is-and-how-you-can-use-it/)

Comment: @L.Page what is console output?

Comment: @L.Page : If the VS debugger is unable catch the exception then I don't think it is logged in the console either.

Comment: @VisualVincent ill try Event Viewer ( never used it).

Comment: @kooda : Great! In addition to my previous comment you can also look for an entry called _".NET Runtime Error"_.

Comment: @VisualVincent i debuged errors with EV as you suggested, in app's error it says  that KernelBase cause the crash, and in .net error it shows "System.ObjectDisposedException
Stack" ill update an qustion aboe with the logs

Comment: What does your application do? Based on the error it appears to be trying to access a serial port that has been disposed.

Comment: Also see these two related posts: [**\[ 1 \]**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22077818), [**\[ 2 \]**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3808885)

Comment: yes, its trying to autoconnect to serialport, but i dont know how to handle it

Comment: i debugged, and yes the error is on this code(ill update)

Comment: You never close or dispose those serial ports when you're done using them (apart from when an error occurs). You must do so before `Next`. To avoid further exceptions insert a null-check as well: `If spObj IsNot Nothing Then spObj.Dispose()`. Also try using the `ExSerialPort` class instead which can be found in an answer in the second link that I shared.

Comment: Calling the `Hex` method on your byte value of 99 seems strange.  `Hex` returns a `String` but you are assigning it to an array index of type  `Byte`.   It seems that you do you have `Option Strict On`.